# Call list of method call signatures on a given objects in Python 3

Tags: python

I ask myself (independent of the question of the best design): Is there a way in python 3 to collect a-priori method call signatures in a list and consecutively
evaluate the method calls afterwards.

Having for example an instance method `f(foo)` defined for a class `C`,
is it possible to collect a sequence / list of signatures `[f(a), f(b), f(c) ...]`
and run later on `myC = C()` the list of calls: `myC.f(a)`, `myC.f(b)`, `myC(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special "call signatures", just gather up some kwargs (or args) however you like and `**` splat them into your invocation.

```
class C:
    def greet(self, name, enthusiasm=False):
        if enthusiasm:
            print(f"OH HI THERE, {name.upper()}!")
        else:
            print(f"Hello, {name}.")


c = C()

for arg in [
    {'name': 'Bob', 'enthusiasm': False},
    {'name': 'Mallory', 'enthusiasm': True},
]:
    c.greet(**arg)
```

This prints out, expectedly,

```
Hello, Bob.
OH HI THERE, MALLORY!
```

Another solution with an equivalent result is to use `functools.partial`, but then you'll need the function at the time of partial contruction:

```
for call in [
    partial(c.greet, "Bob"),
    partial(c.greet, "Mallory", enthusiasm=True),
]:
    call()
```

Comment: I agree and thanks -- this works and I also considered that .. But is this operator style of applying a class member function onto a object possible in Python ? It is not a design or style question -- it is more a investigation of possibilities.

Comment: What do you mean with "is this operator style of applying a class member function onto a object possible in Python"? You can use `getattr(inst, "c")` if you want the `c` method from `inst`, and then call it with the arguments you like.

Comment: Thanks that mate, that corrected the style. First post on stackoverflow.

Comment: AKX, I mean it in the mathematical sense: For example you can write a + b, but also O (a b) where O is the operator on a b. In that sense I wanted to check, if it is possible to take out just the signature (including the symbol of the method) as O and apply it onto an object. The advantage would be that you could have a list of calls applied to a bunch of objects in a list. But the Pythonic way is also ok, but a little bit lengthy in my opinion. In a typing system the method should be bound to a class clearly to have the check, if the method is applicable onto the object. Cheers

Comment: Well, for the _particular_ example of `a + b`, see the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/operator.html#module-operator) module: `operator.add(a, b)` -> `partial(operator.add, a, b)()` ...

Comment: There they have it .. but Python is anyway quite flexible ... I was just curious, if some Python crack found a clean way doing the way I asked for. Cheers, @AKX and thx.

Comment: I'm... happy I could help, but I'm still not sure what you were going for initially.